# Facebook getUser returns wrong ID

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, sdk

I have an problem in my app. The only thing I need from a user is there facebook id. After they log onto facebook they are redirected back to my app and I can get the userID with $facebook->getUser(). This works fine except when the user has chosen a username on facebook. Then I get a really weird long ID that is different from the userid.

To clarify, let's say I ask the userid from a user that hasn't set a username, I get for example the id: 1234567891.
When a user has set a username, I get an ID like: 100002339295322.

Anyone maby knows how I can solve this ?

If you need code samples of how I do things, I do them as told on the facebook developers site: http://developers.facebook.com .

With friendly greetings,
Bob

PS: I use the CodeIgniter framework and the official facebook php sdk

**/// EDIT \**

The problem is solved. Apparently it had something to do with the datatype I used for the field. I changed it from int to varchar and now everything is working.

Comment: What makes you think that the 'long' user ids you get are wrong? How do you get the 'real' user id that you use for comparison?

Comment: Tried them like: http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1234567891 and the short versions worked, the long ones didn't.

Comment: I just checked a test account user id, and it matches your 'long' format (the account also has a user name). Using it as the id parameter for the profile page works as well. So I guess you should check your assumptions - maybe the user accounts you are testing with do not have a profile page for some reason? (It is highly unlikely that a core SDK function like getUser() returns wrong data.)

Comment: Apparently it had something to do with the datatype I used for the field. I changed it to varchar and now everything is working. You were right that both id's are valid. Thnak you for the help!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, and found out that after v2.0 API user_id is app scoped. I had two user_id for the same user's profile but different application, and both are valid for their respective app.

You can reach the user profile with

```
http://facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/<USER_ID>
```

You may also query the graph api, using the app token and the app scoped user id.

Ref.: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Comment: I had the same problem as OP and this fixed it.  I was trying to link to the user's profile using this `https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=LONG_USER_ID` and it wasn't working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not all facebook users have **usernames** but they ALL have **user ids**. (e.g. it's optional to have an alphanumeric username, just gives easy access - facebook.com/johnsmith or smth)

Your best bet is to store the ID (the 10 or so digit number) and if you're storing names, perhaps store their first name like stackoverflow does.

Comment: The thing is I am getting the userid but when a user has set a username, I don't get the right userid with $facebook->getUser() but a really weird one. Thats the problem ;).

Comment: What do you mean weird? Could you provide a example?

Answer (score 0):

For those coming here after 1 May 2014, Test Apps now default to the v2 API, which will cause problems if your app was built using v1. See last post in the FAQ here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps